# Hey Folks I have a problem while installing Hydro ROS on ubuntu 15.04 64bit

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

eldiwiny@eldiwiny-HP-2000-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop-full
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
ros-indigo-desktop-full : Depends: ros-indigo-desktop but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-indigo-perception but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-indigo-simulators but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
eldiwiny@eldiwiny-HP-2000-Notebook-PC:~$

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240679/hey-folks--i-have-a-problem-while-installing-hydro-ros-on-ubuntu-15.04-64bit/) by [marwa eldiwiny](https://answers.ros.org/users/27638/marwa-eldiwiny/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2016-07-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As stated in the setup instructions, ROS **Indigo** only has apt packages for Ubuntu 13.10 and 14.04: http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu

ROS **Hydro** (mentioning in your question title) is no longer supported, although the binaries may still install on Ubuntu 12.04: http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/Ubuntu

Ubuntu 15.04 is no longer supported, so it is no longer receiving updated apt packages of ROS.

Why these specific versions of ROS and Ubuntu? Do you have a particular project in mind?

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2